# Deleting upto a line

Tags: bash, perl, shell, sed, scripting

I have a line that looks like:

```
  foo cat dog =      -48.34277635  foo(horse->0) =      -60.34277635
```

and I only want the last set of numbers:

```
-60.34277635
```

The line is formatted with that exact spacing. I've looked everywhere for a simpler solution, but I can't find anything without chopping the file piece by piece by piece until I get it down to what I want. The only ways I have to do it is horribly inefficient and was wondering if there were any other ways of doing it. Normally, I would use sed to grab a specific character/word, and delete from there back. With as many times as words are repeated in my string, I can't easily do that.

The length of the numbers can change too, but only the trailing decimals.

If at all possible, help in Perl, or Bash/Shell would be best.

Comment: Show your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -oE '[0-9.-]+$' file
```

or

```
awk '{print $NF}' file
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I get the -oE part, but would you mind explaining the rest?

Comment: `[0-9.-]+$` is a regular expression which describes the last part of your line. `[...]` lists the allowed characters (0 to 9, a dot and a minus sign). The plus means that the previous character must occur at least once. Here is the previous character one character from the allowed character list within `[...]`. `$` marks the end of line.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want just the last field on each line then you can write this in Perl

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;
my @data;
push @data, (split)[-1] while <$fh>;
```

Comment: Perl, right? I forgot that you could do (split)[-1]. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Perl. I'm sorry I should have said

Comment: It's ok. Looked familiar. Wanted to check.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and specifying field 8 (assuming the format doesn't change), here's what I get:

```
$ cat testfile 
foo cat dog =      -48.34277635  foo(horse->0) =      -60.34277635
$ awk '{print $8}' < testfile
-60.34277635
```

Answer (score 0):

BASH builtin way:

```
#!/bin/bash

line='foo cat dog =      -48.34277635  foo(horse->0) =      -60.34277635'
echo "${line##* }"
```

outputs:

```
-60.34277635
```

Comment: Why does that work? Does the second # represent the second instance of a number?

Comment: @jcklasseter: `##` means *remove the largest possible matching string from the beginning of the variable's contents* and `* ` means *match anything up until space*. [Source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Answer (score 0):

awk -F 'delimiter' '{print $NF}' - if you need the last column

awk -F 'delimiter' '{print $index}' - if you need index with a specific column. Please not here the index starts with 1